# Windows Install Error

Tags: windows, computer-building

So recently I messed around with some of the internals of my PC just to get the cable management looking better. It worked, however I had one problem: I seated in my HD audio cable wrong, so I couldn't use my headphones. This morning, I reseated the cable properly, and when I turned on my PC Windows was trying to repair itself due to a hardware change. However, Windows cannot repair itself. Right now I'm on Ubuntu trying to set up a LIVEUSB (no dvd drive in the computer to use), but I haven't even gotten that far yet. How can I repair my Windows install?

Comment: Any particular version of Windows? So its not booting into windows now? More details please.

Comment: Its Windows 7. It attempts to do the "startup repair", but that doesn't work at all. It just continues in an infinite loop. My hard drive and everything else in my computer are still recognized by the BIOS, and the files are trying to be loaded by Windows. SO it must be a problem with Windows and not a Hard Drive error.

Comment: If you can get the F8 screen, choose "repair your computer", when it loads cancel any repair that automatically runs, continue to load Recovery environment, once it loads select startup repair from the tools menu, see if running it manually can repair it, you may have to do this manual repair up to 3 times before it will boot correctly

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get to "load recovery environment" or the F8 screen. It automatically does the repair.

Comment: Update here, my BOOTMGR is missing.

Comment: You will need a usb dvd drive, then boot from a W7 install disc to get the recovery environment.